# python - how to properly search and count keywords in a csv.gz file

Tags: python

I have this unix command line code that does this succesfully:

```
$ zcat export-cars.csv.gz | awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"};{print $6}' | grep -i bmw | wc -l
222
```

I'm trying to do a similar using python (gzip, split) with this count, but getting a count of `0`:

```
import gzip
mycar = 'bmw'
lines = gzip.open('export-cars.csv.gz')
mycat = sum(line.split(';')[5] == mycar for line in lines)

print (mycar)
```

Where is the problem? I tried different column number `[6]` and no luck.

Comment: Post output of `zcat export-cars.csv.gz` here.

Comment: `print` is the first thing to reach for when debugging.  If you replace your `sum` line by `for line in lines: print(repr(line), repr(line.split(";")[5]), repr(mycar))`, what do you see?  (Using `repr` makes it easier to spot differences.)

Comment: For obvious reasons, I can't paste my data here. But I appreciate how to debug this. I did get some output though when I used `print(repr(line}`. `AttributeError: GzipFile instance has no attribute 'split'`. I'm running python `2.6.6`. Is that problem?